# Resource directory has the same name as a Class without ".class"

Tags: java, jls, openjdk-11

I have the following directory structure within my project:

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── soebes
│   │           └── packages
│   │               └── f1
│   │                   └── First.java
│   └── resources
│       └── com
│           └── soebes
│               └── packages
│                   └── f1
│                       └── First
│                           └── test.txt
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── soebes
    │           └── packages
    │               └── f1
    │                   └── FirstTest.java
    └── resources
        └── com
            └── soebes
                └── packages
                    └── f1
                        └── FirstTest
                            └── test.txt
```

As you can see I have a package name `com/soebes/packages/f1/First` in my resources directory which has the same name as a class in my `src/main/java/.../First.java` directory (except the `.java`). The whole project compiles without any issue.

If you take a look into the resulting `target` directory it looks fine:

```
target/
├── classes
│   └── com
│       └── soebes
│           └── packages
│               └── f1
│                   ├── First
│                   │   └── test.txt
│                   └── First.class
....
└── test-classes
    └── com
        └── soebes
            └── packages
                └── f1
                    ├── FirstTest
                    │   └── test.txt
                    └── FirstTest.class
```

Update: Also the resulting JAR looks fine and can built without any issue:

```
package (main)$ unzip -t target/packages-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Archive:  target/packages-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    testing: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     OK
    testing: META-INF/                OK
    testing: com/                     OK
    testing: com/soebes/              OK
    testing: com/soebes/packages/     OK
    testing: com/soebes/packages/f1/   OK
    testing: com/soebes/packages/f1/First/   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/          OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.jvm.packages/   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.jvm.packages/packages-examples/   OK
    testing: com/soebes/packages/f1/First/test.txt   OK
    testing: com/soebes/packages/f1/First.class   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.jvm.packages/packages-examples/pom.xml   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.jvm.packages/packages-examples/pom.properties   OK
    testing: META-INF/INDEX.LIST      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of target/packages-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
```

The question is simply: Is this allowed?

Compiling on plain command line works fine. Also using in in IDEA IntelliJ as well.

Eclipse seemed to be having issues with that. It produces an errors like `The type FirstTest collides with a package`... it looks like that it analysis the `target` directory.

I've already searched through the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html) but couldn't find anything related to that or may be I have overseen something like that.

From a technical point of view there shouldn't be an issue the class is `FirstTest.class` which is a file and the directory are two different things.

So in consequence if this allowed the behaviour in Eclipse is a bug or if this is not allowed it would meant IDEA and Maven/Javac having an issue?

The given example can be found on [Github](https://github.com/khmarbaise/package) for further investigation.

- Environment:

  - Apache Maven:

    Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
    Maven home: /Users/khmarbaise/tools/maven
    Java version: 11.0.8, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Users/khmarbaise/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt
    Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
  - Eclipse:

    Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
    Build id: 20200615-1200
  - IDEA IntelliJ

    IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
    Build #IU-203.6682.168, built on December 29, 2020
    Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 x86_64
    VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
    macOS 10.14.6

Update: 02/15/2021: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571218

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, except that it is a convention in Java to restrict package names to only lowercase letters and digits.

Comment: Yeah I know about the convention for the packages. But as you mentioned it's a convention nothing which defined in language specification (that I know of) ... I'm searching if there is a limitation somehow which I don't know or never heard about it...

Comment: One approach to get more insights would be to ask the Eclipse developers themselves (mailing list / bug tracker?)